# the android app crashes or not installs after building using android studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, sdk

When i run my app in my device [which runs on 7.1] The app runs well but when i run it on  my opo which runs on 4.4 it crashed and when i try to run it on a android 5.0 device it gave app cannot install error

I've build>generate signed apk and have used that

I'm basically new to all this so if anyone can help me out what the issue is i would be glad

my activity_main code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.bingobean.pitchblack.MainActivity"
android:weightSum="1">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/android"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:text="Pitch black"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="118dp"
    android:layout_height="109dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="144dp"
    android:text="Hit it!"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

My mainactivity is

```
package com.bingobean.pitchblack;

import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btn;
ImageView img;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            WallpaperManager wallmgr = 
WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            try {
                wallmgr.setResource(+ R.drawable.android);
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wallpaper is set", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

}
}
```

My Androidmanifest is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.bingobean.pitchblack">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What *error log* is showing ? Post it.

Comment: I didn't get any error log. it says apk generated successfully.

Comment: Track  error while installing application in device.

Answer (score 0):

check your app level build.gradle file in , in that file  You have these two attributes  :

- minSdkVersion 16
- targetSdkVersion 23 this

// these are api levels

Change them to according to your requirement .

Comment: So when i run them via adb using my phone it installs but then when i take the apk and manually try to install it says app cannot install. Why is that

Answer (score 0):

Ditto to what Hamza  said, you must have set your min and target api to not be compatible with kitkat. as for the app not installed, that is either 1: you have an app with same package name installed, 2: the LAUNCH and DEFAULT intents aren't set (they are it seems), or 3: it somehow got corrupted. Please post your logcat for when it crashes. Root your phone and download LogCat.

Comment: okay the app doesnt crash i'm not sure what solved it and for the api its set at min 17 and target 25. After building the app when i try to install it by moving it to sd card, it fails. But when i run the app via adb it installs automatically and works.